# Form serialize is not working in safari?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, safari

I'm trying to get serialized form data, so I can attach the data with ajax request.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="addCategoryForm" action="/category/add" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Category Name">
    <button type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

and when I try to serialize the form using the code given below:

```
$('#addCategoryForm').serialize();
```

It works perfect in Chrome, Mozilla etc, but in safari It's giving empty string.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem when I tried to define or extend the prototype of Object. If you're defining prototype for Object, It will conflict with some of the jquery functions.